# Can I connect a 15 A surge protector to a 13 A extension cord?

Tags: power-electronics

As someone who’s studied engineering, I should be able to answer this question. However, a quick search online has me confused.

Provided what I’m plugging in (a laptop drawing relatively little power) doesn’t exceed the extension cord rating, there should be no issue.

Advice online suggests otherwise. Is there something about consumer electronics I don’t know? Or, perhaps online advice is merely simplified (and presented inaccurately) to be foolproof.

I see a similar question here, but again I suspect those answers are inaccurate so as to be foolproof.

Answer (score 2):

> Provided what I’m plugging in (a laptop drawing relatively little power) doesn’t exceed the extension cord rating, there should be no issue.

This is correct. If your load is well under 13A, you shouldn't see any issues.

The obvious counterargument is that with this setup, the 13A extension cord could fail before the surge protector kicks in to protect the system. Like, with a 14A load. So, generally, your setup is not recommended, especially for a long-term installation.

Answer (score -1):

The 15A power surge must be connected to an extension of equivalent or greater a/m.
I’m not a pro electrician though.